# Unable to access URL in Retrosheet package

Tags: r

I am trying to access data for all the schedule/location of the baseball events happened so far.

but I am unable to overcome this error.

> getRetrosheet("schedule", 1995)
>   Error in getRetrosheet("schedule", 1995) : 
>     'http://www.retrosheet.org/schedule/1995sked.txt' is not a valid url

Comment: As the error suggests, that is not a valid url. If you try opening it in your browser you'll see you get an Error 404 message. Going up a level to [https://www.retrosheet.org/schedule/](https://www.retrosheet.org/schedule/) shows that each of the years is actually a zip file. Where is the `getRetrosheet` function defined? Is that something you wrote or is it from a package?

Comment: i am able to download that data in zip file from URL. i used > devtools::install_github("rmscriven/retrosheet") and then > getRetrosheet("schedule", 1995)
Error in getRetrosheet("schedule", 1995) : 
  'http://www.retrosheet.org/schedule/1995sked.txt' is not a valid url

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the links generated by the retrosheet R package are out of date.

Link to the retrosheet package is here [Retrosheet Github](https://github.com/rmscriven/retrosheet). The last commit was 4 years ago, which may be why it is out of date.

It almost generated the correct link, but if you go to retrosheet and inspect the 1995 download link it goes to http://www.retrosheet.org/schedule/1995SKED.ZIP and downloads a zip file instead of grabbing the text file itself. This is stated here: https://github.com/rmscriven/retrosheet/issues/5

There are a few forks that are ahead of master in the repo and it looks like they fixed the issue for themselves, so check those out. You can either fork it yourself and fix it for your needs, or try to use one of the forks that someone has fixed like [this one](https://github.com/gandersen101/retrosheet).

Hope this helps!

Comment: i am able to download the zip file from that url and it has a text file. but i dont know how to use in R for finding schedules for any year. can you please help

Comment: That was the point of the package correct? So you need to update your project to use a version of the package that is working with the zip files, or you can download all of the text files here http://www.retrosheet.org/schedule/schedule.zip and use them in your R project based on `year + "SKED.TXT"`

Comment: thanks, i am new to R, can you help me in reading the files for any year using this package. please!

Comment: I attempted to use the package, but it is not maintained and I don't have the time to get it to work for you. Download the directory of files and google how to import them based on a file path. This should help [r resources](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/reading-data-from-txt-csv-files-r-base-functions) Please mark my answer as correct if you found it useful!